# Why does MaxentTagger tag numbers as NN sometimes?

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, maxent

I am trying to tag a HTML page full of space-separated numbers like "5320412185 5320412184 5320412189..." to observe how the tagger behaves with numbers. I'm using `english-left3words-distsim.tagger` in the constructor. I'm observing on the console that most of the numbers are tagged as `CD` but at times there are also numbers getting tagged as `NN`. I searched on the FAQ page of nlp.stanford.edu but I couldn't find this there. Can anyone help me in understanding this?

I don't know if I should need to mention this: I'm feeding each number separately to the tagger by splitting the huge input(1045000 numbers!) based on space-delimiter.

Comment: Hi, my first answer was not correct, I realized that I didn't understand totally your problem. Now I have revised my answer, it should be the solution of your problem. Have you check it yet?

Answer (score 1):

*From Part-of-Speech Tagging Guidelines for the Penn Treebank Project (3rd Revision)*

Sometimes, it is unclear whether one is cardinal number or a noun. In general, it should be tagged as a
cardinal number (CD) even when its sense is not clearly that of a numeral.

```
EXAMPLE: one/CD of the best reasons
```

But if it could be pluralized or modified by an adjective in a particular context, it is a common noun (NN).

```
EXAMPLE: the only (good) one/NN of its kind
         (cf. the only (good) ones/NNS of their kind)
```

In the collocation another one, one should also be tagged as a common noun (NN).

Hyphenated fractions one-half, three-fourths, seven-eighths, one-and-a-half, seven-and-three-eighths should
be tagged as adjectives (JJ) when they are prenominal modifiers, but as adverbs (RB) if they could be
replaced by double or twice.

For further reading: http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1603&context=cis_reports

Comment: Thanks for your response @Saibot. What you explained seems to be for numbers expressed in english words. But my input page has actual numerals of which some are being tagged as "NNS" and "NN". I shall go through this PDF. Thank you very much for this file!